# How do I get Deployment Mode or ClickOnce in my Publish menu

Tags: publish

I do not have Deployment mode or ClickOnce in the Publish menu in my version of Visual Studio.

I have a very simple windows app for which I want to create a standalone executable that I can double click and it just opens.

Currently I have only one choice when I right click on the solution and select Publish, as seen in the screenshot:
[Publish Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07rth.png)
This leads only to the creation of an install file that is not standalone.

I have seen many many posts that tell me how to create a standalone exe by using the Deployment mode or ClickOnce settings, but I can't find a post on how to get the option of Deployment mode or ClickOnce in the Publish menu.  Do I need a different version of Visual Studio? Please see VS details below.

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.4.2
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.4.2+33122.133
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Community

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.4.326.54890
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.4.326.54890
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

C# Tools   4.4.0-6.22565.8+53091686b435746d62a5df56abfab0e71203d83a
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

NuGet Package Manager   6.4.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.0.62207.28050
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript Tools   17.0.10921.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.4.0-6.22565.8+53091686b435746d62a5df56abfab0e71203d83a
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.4.0-beta.22512.4+525d5109e389341bb90b144c24e2ad1ceec91e7b
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.